# How to delete a comment via an HTTP GET link in an email

Tags: 7, comments, advertising

On my site, moderators are notified of comments via email whenever a new comment is posted. I would like to offer them a one-click approve/delete feature directly from the email.

There is an approve comment link, so I can easily put that link into the email for them to approve the comment directly.

However comments are deleted via a form - an HTTP post - so I can't do that from a link in an email as far as I know. At least that's how it is on my site - not sure whether the form behaviour is normal or is because I have Mollom installed.

Is there a way to delete a comment directly from a link in an email?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

Obviously you don't want to allow just anyone to delete any comment.

The authentication step is to require the user to be logged in with "*administer comments*" permission.

Alternatively, you could perhaps use a token in the querystring to check access to delete the comment.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu
 */
function MY_MODULE_menu() {

  $items['action/comment/%/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete comment',
    'page callback' => 'MY_MODULE_action_comment_delete',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('administer comments'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Menu callback
 * Delete comment via GET request
 */
function MY_MODULE_action_comment_delete($cid){

  try{
    // Delete the comment
    comment_delete($cid);
    drupal_set_message(t('The comment and all its replies have been deleted.'));
    watchdog('MY_MODULE', 'Deleted comment @cid and its replies.', array('@cid' => $cid));
    // Clear the cache so an anonymous user sees that his comment was deleted.
    cache_clear_all();
  }catch(Exception $e){
    drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem deleting the comment.'));
    watchdog_exception('MY_MODULE', $e);
  }

}
```

The path to delete a comment would then be:

http://www.example.com/action/comment/12/delete

Where "12" is the comment cid.

Comment: That looks good, thanks. I'll try it out and accept once I can. The comments are pre-moderated, they don't appear until they are accepted, so I think we won't need to clear the cache.